# How do I get the FLTK library to run in Visual Studio 2012 Prfessional?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fltk

I would like to start off with saying I am a very novice programmer.

I have downloaded and re-downloaded many different libraries claiming to be the FLTK library that will run with Visual Studio 2012, and after reading countless ways to install it, I finally got one way to work, and tested it with a sample code to open a window, but all that opens is the console. I have made the changes in the properties menu, I have added the FL folder to input and the .lib files to the lib folder, but this is all I can get. Can someone please help?

```
    #include <FL/Fl.h>
    #include <FL/Fl_box.h>
    #include <FL/Fl_Window.h>
```

//***************************

```
    int main() 
  {
    Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
    Fl_Box box(0,0,200,200, "Hey, I mean, He llo, World! ");
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
  }
```

Comment: Have you set the linker subsystem to windows?

Comment: If it is set to Windows, I get the error                                   1>------ Build started: Project: LED, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Chip\Desktop\Programs\ENGR. Code\LED\LED\Debug\LED.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Do the projects in the fltk.../IDE/VS2010 folder build?  If they do, check the project settings of say buttons.vcxproj against what you have.

Comment: Something is not quite right: WinMain is defined in fl_call_main.c which is compiled into fltkd.lib.  Is it possibly not picking up your fltkd.lib - have a look in Project Properties/Linker/Command Line.  Where does it think fltkd.lib is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

A decade ago, Greg Ercolano made an amazing video *[How To Get Started Building FLTK With Visual Studio 7.0](http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk-videos/fltk-ms-vs-build.html)* . I am pretty sure you will be able to setup your FLTK project in VS 2012 after you see the mentioned video. Good luck.

Comment: I did it this way, but the newest version of the FLTK library I could get doing it this way was too old to work in VS 2012. They have newer versions, but they are in .tar.gz files, which I can't download

Comment: Thank you very much, though. If you know of a way to get the .tar files, that would really help.

Comment: Actually, I got it, finally! Thanks again!

Comment: It very well might but I can't get it to, which is why I'm seeking guidance.